# It is possible to share CloudFirestore data Firebase - documents between different APP in the same project?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have 2 APP which one of it has to retrieve some data from firestore database of the other APP.
I see with Firebase there is a possibility to create several APP under same project, thus I assume it is possible to take some data from a database of the other app.
There is some configuration to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to configure the same firebase project in both apps and you can easily read-write data .